# Equations to determine center of arc with start at origin, second known point, and given central angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I am trying to understand two equations I found in a piece of code. A two dimensional position vector which begins at an unknown point $(h, k)$ initially points at the origin, $(0, 0)$. This vector is then rotated through a given arc of $\theta$ degrees and stops at a known point $(x, y)$. Using the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the terminal point and the angle $\theta$, the following equations are used to determine the point $(h, k)$:

$$h = \frac{x(1-\cos\theta)-y\sin\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}$$
$$k = \frac{x\sin\theta+y(1-\cos\theta)}{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}$$

Here is an example with specific values:
[image: example problem]
In the figure above, $x = 1$, $y = 5$, and $\theta = -53.1301^\circ$. Using these values and the above equations results in $(h, k) = (5.5000, 1.5000)$.

My question is how are the equations for $h$ and $k$ derived?

I understand the initial vector position and final position form the two radii of a sector. These radii and a line between the points $(0, 0)$ and $(x, y)$ form an isosceles triangle. It appears the numerators from the above equations are a matrix vector product derived from a common two dimensional rotation matrix where where $\cos\theta$ has been replaced with $(1 - \cos\theta)$. However, I do not understand why or the role of the value in the denominator. Can someone please explain how and why these equations work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From
$$
\pmatrix{x-h\\ y-k}=
\pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta}
\pmatrix{-h\\ -k}
$$
one finds
$$
\pmatrix{x\\ y}=
\pmatrix{1-\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & 1-\cos\theta}
\pmatrix{h\\ k}
$$
and
$$
\pmatrix{h\\ k}=
\pmatrix{1-\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & 1-\cos\theta}^{-1}
\pmatrix{x\\ y},
$$
which is your formula, because:
$$
\pmatrix{1-\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & 1-\cos\theta}^{-1}
={1\over(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}
\pmatrix{1-\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & 1-\cos\theta}.
$$